# Correct use of XML annotations, fields and structs in custom UnmarshalXML function

Tags: go

Consider the following struct:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Name string
    Meta map[string]interface{}
}
```

Which has the following UnmarshalXML function:

```
func (m *MyStruct) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    var v struct {
        XMLName xml.Name //`xml:"myStruct"`
        Name    string   `xml:"name"`
        Meta    struct {
            Inner []byte `xml:",innerxml"`
        } `xml:"meta"`
    }

    err := d.DecodeElement(&v, &start)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    m.Name = v.Name
    myMap := make(map[string]interface{})

    // ... do the mxj magic here ... -

    temp := v.Meta.Inner

    prefix := "<meta>"
    postfix := "</meta>"
    str := prefix + string(temp) + postfix
    //fmt.Println(str)
    myMxjMap, err := mxj.NewMapXml([]byte(str))
    myMap = myMxjMap

    // fill myMap
    //m.Meta = myMap
    m.Meta = myMap["meta"].(map[string]interface{})
    return nil
}
```

My problem with this code is these lines:

```
prefix := "<meta>"
postfix := "</meta>"
str := prefix + string(temp) + postfix
myMxjMap, err := mxj.NewMapXml([]byte(str))
myMap = myMxjMap
//m.Meta = myMap
m.Meta = myMap["meta"].(map[string]interface{})
```

My question is how I make the correct use of the xml annotations (,innerxml etc), fields and structs, so I don't have to manually pre-/append the `<meta></meta>` tags afterwards to get the whole Meta field as a single map.

The full code example is here: http://play.golang.org/p/Q4_tryubO6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xml` package doesn't provide a way to unmarshal XML into `map[string]interface{}` because there is no single way to do it and in some cases it is not possible. A map doesn't preserve order of the elements (that is important in XML) and doesn't allow elements with duplicate keys.

`mxj` package that you used in your example has some rules how to unmarshal arbitrary XML into Go map. If your requirements do not conflict with these rules you can use `mxj` package to do all parsing and do not use `xml` package at all:

```
// I am skipping error handling here
m, _ := mxj.NewMapXml([]byte(s))
mm := m["myStruct"].(map[string]interface{})
myStruct.Name = mm["name"].(string)
myStruct.Meta = mm["meta"].(map[string]interface{})
```

Full example: http://play.golang.org/p/AcPUAS0QMj

Comment: Well not exactly the answer I had hoped for, but I guess it can't be helped. Your proposal wouldn't work in my specific situation, but at least you pointed out the limitations of the Go xml package, which is why I'm accepting this answer.